# ReactJs Redirect on state variable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redirect

I am trying to get json via ajax and if my response variable is acceptable redirect using react router. How can I achieve that?

```
successRedirect(){
    if (this.responseCode.equals("what I need")) {
        router.transitionTo('/')
    }
}

createCheckout() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: this.data,
        success: function(response) {
            this.setState({
                response: response,
                responseCode: response.result.code
            });
        }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    })
}
```

Function must be called after response is taken. For example I have this code and in render response is taken and shown after some  time:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Response - {this.state.responseCode}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.. so call the function in `success` ?

Comment: I got undefind this.responseCode

Comment: Don't you mean `this.state.responseCode` ?

Comment: also what's `.equals` ? Is that psuedocode?

Comment: this.state.responseCode.equals is not a function

Comment: of course its not a function, why would it be?

Comment: I got this error in my console

Comment: do you mean `this.state.responseCode === 'some value'` ?

Comment: as a suggestion, it looks like you are using jQuery for ajax requests. Stop using it, try something like axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was with this line:

```
if (this.responseCode.equals("what I need")) {
```

Items that get added via `this.setState` are available on the `this.state` object. Also JavaScript does not supply an `equals` function, but you can do comparisons with `===`

```
if (this.state.responseCode === "what I need") {
```